# Convert Excel to JSON format in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, xlsx

I am trying to convert imported excel file to JSON in ReactJS, I am using npm XLSX package but i am facing difficulties to convert excel to required json format. Any help would be appreciated.

**Excel :**

[image]

**Expected JSON :**

```
[
{"class" :{"name:"B"},"Currency":{"currencyCode":"USD},"Price":[{"date":"01-01-2012","price":123},{"date":"01-01-2013","price":134},{"date":"01-01-2014","price":135}]},{"class" :{"name:"C"},"Currency":{"currencyCode":"USD},"Price":[{"date":"01-01-2012","price":345},{"date":"01-01-2013","price":321},{"date":"01-01-2014","price":232}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem of converting Excel to Json in excel. You can find many tools online converting Json to Excel but I didn't find many for the reverse job.

Please browse this link
[1]: https://infointrend.com/how-to-generate-json-format-records-in-excel-without-vba-programming/

This explains how to generate the JSON format records in excel and copy paste the result into a text file and save it as JSON.

Hope this would help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33825206)